# Double "Could have"? Is it possible?

Tags: grammaticality

This doesn't fit into the rules of Conditional sentences, but is it possible to say so? Here is the sentence:
I could have told you this if I could have known before.

Comment: An interesting question.  I don't think there is anything *grammatically* wrong with it, but it does not sound fluent or natural.  For one thing, it doesn't quite make sense: I could have told you if I *could have* known?   But *could have* is only possibility, and obviously I only could have told you a thing if I *did* know it, not if I *could have* known it.

Comment: I could have told you this if I had known before, would be standard.

Comment: Your example utterance *I could have told you this if I could have known before* is syntactically fine - it's just a rather unlikely thing to say (apparently for some reason I ***couldn't*** have known this before, as opposed to the far more likely assertion that I simply ***didn't*** know it before). But if you can make sense of that, syntactic rules certainly won't stop you from saying it.

Answer (score 2):

"Could" is often used as the past of "can" as well as a hypothetical conditional a bit like "would".

In some cases, "could" might be used as a conditional on one side of a conditional sentence and as the past of "can" on the other (carrying the meaning "... was/were able to ...").

Such sentences wouldn't necessarily break the rules of conditional sentences.

For a second conditional example:

- "I could help you if I could get out of this locked room."

A (less likely) third conditional example might be:

- "I could have gone to the gig if I could have bought the tickets."

However, there is an extra difference in meaning between "I could have done something" and "I [was/have been] able to do something": the former implies that, though you could have done it, you didn't in fact do it, while the second carries the meaning that since you were able to do it, you actually did!

To prevent confusion, a native speaker would be less likely to use a "... could have ... could have ..." pattern in any third conditional, more likely opting for a "... could have ... had been able to ..." option:

- "I could have gone to the gig if I'd been able to buy the tickets."

Nevertheless, the " ... could have ... could have ..." pattern doesn't actually break any rules that I'm familiar with on how to form third conditional sentences.

Comment: Yes, well said re the had been able to.

Comment: I disagree "there is an extra difference in meaning between" ***could*** and ***be able to***. The only actual difference is that the Perfect forms *(I could have done it / I was able to have done it)* both strongly imply *...but I **didn't** actually do it*. Whereas *I could do it / I was able to do it* both often imply *...and I **did***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I see your point about the formal tenses.  I'll edit the answer as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I've cast my previously withheld upvote. It's not so serious now it's acknowledged in our comments, but I'm sure you can find a way to avoid giving a misleading impression in the answer text when you get around to it! :)